# Web scraping with lxml and requests

Tags: python, web, request, lxml, screen-scraping

I have a [web page](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.et.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaEKIAQGYAQu4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuoAgM&sid=1bc09296ee139ec3cb0edce87d7fb20a&dcid=1&class_interval=1&dest_id=67&dest_type=country&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hlrd=0&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&src=index&ss=Eesti&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Eesti&ssb=empty&sshis=0&traveller=other&nflt=ht_id%3D204%3B&lsf=ht_id%7C204%7C221&unchecked_filter=hoteltype) with hotels, where i want to get all the hotel names. I made a code following instructions from [this page](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/), but no success.
My code is here:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('web page url')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

hotel_name = tree.xpath('//span[@title="sr-hotel__name"]/text()')

print(hotel_name)
```

All I get is an empty list. Any help?

Comment: You should use beautifulsoup for scraping purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a user-agent:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get('http://www.booking.com/searchresults.et.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaEKIAQGYAQu4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuoAgM&sid=1bc09296ee139ec3cb0edce87d7fb20a&dcid=1&class_interval=1&dest_id=67&dest_type=country&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hlrd=0&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&src=index&ss=Eesti&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Eesti&ssb=empty&sshis=0&traveller=other&nflt=ht_id%3D204%3B&lsf=ht_id%7C204%7C221&unchecked_filter=hoteltype'
                    , headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(page.text)
hotel_name = tree.xpath('//span[@class="sr-hotel__name"]/text()')

print(hotel_name)
```

Which will give you:

```
['\nHotel Telegraaf\n', '\nRadisson Blu Hotel Olümpia\n', '\nRadisson Blu Sky Hotel\n', '\nPark Inn by Radisson Central Tallinn\n', '\nPark Inn by Radisson Meriton Conference & Spa Hotel Tallinn\n', '\nMerchants House Hotel\n', '\nSwissotel Tallinn\n', '\nMy City Hotel\n', '\nNordic Hotel Forum\n', '\nHotel Palace by TallinnHotels\n', '\nHotel Ülemiste\n', '\nTallink City Hotel\n', '\nHotel London by Tartuhotels\n', '\nJohan Design & SPA Hotel\n', '\nThe von Stackelberg Hotel Tallinn\n']
```

But you should read their [TOS](http://www.booking.com/content/terms.et.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGmIAQGYAQu4AQrIAQzYAQPoAQGoAgM;sid=52cedf70cb08d87dee23f69f173a8650;dcid=12):

*Our services are only for personal and non-commercial use. Consequently, you will not be allowed on our web site available through the content, information, software, products or services of a commercial or compete for the purpose of reselling link (deep link) to use, copy, monitor (eg, spiders, scrape), display, download download or reproduce.*

Answer (score 0):

You retrieving an empty list because the html is generated by JavaScript.

So to proceed a bit of a roadmap:

1. Use google inspect XHR;
2. Determine the parameters & header to execute the javascript
3. Passing [parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)
4. Passing [enter link description here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)
5. and combine it like: requests.get(url, params=payload, header=header)

That sad, you should take in consideration to respect the website owner rules and [robots.txt](http://www.booking.com/robots.txt).

In addition of "Arbaz Siddiqui: there are also more complete packages, like beautiful soup or scrapy selenium.

Comment: Nevertheless i also recommend [the video tutorial of Chris Hawkes][1].
  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrsUuVAJh5U

Comment: lxml is one of the best html parsers around so not sure why you think bs4 is a better option, also the data is not generated using js.

Comment: I absolutely agree regarding lxml. And no i don't think beautifulsoup is better I only suggest it as an alternative because bs4 and scrapy are a layer above lxml.

Comment: which could be helpful if interested in alternative approach as  Arbaz Siddiqui suggested. But as you see i'm really new here :)  actually this is my first answer I've written. In advance for my next answer i will try to avoid suggestions and write and more pragmatic answer like yours because basically what you have written is what I ment.